# Remove Windows partition permanently

Tags: windows

I used to have windows7 as the only os in my laptop.

A few months back I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows and now getting used to it, I love it and want to make it my primary os and permanently delete windows for good.

How can I delete Windows without getting any problems with Ubuntu and make my whole hard disk available to Ubuntu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to backup your files and important data and do a fresh Ubuntu install using the whole disk this time. Chances are when you installed you installed Ubuntu on a partition after your Windows one. In your case, re-sizing partitions can take a long time and could result is lost data, as you'd have to resize 'backwards' to take up the space that Windows once took up.